# Combining filtered and bool queries in ES

Tags: elasticsearch

I’m having troubles with combining two queries.
First one:

```
{
  query: {
    filtered: {filter:{bool: {must_not: [{ids: {values: ["one", "two"]}}]}}}
  }
}
```

Second one:

```
{
  query: {
    bool: {
      must_not: [
        { wildcard: {url: "*.biz"} }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

If I run them separately, they works just fine. However, if I combine them into:

```
{
  query: {
    filtered: {filter:{bool: {must_not: [{ids: {values: ["one", "two"]}}]}}},
    bool: {must_not: [{ wildcard: {url: "*.biz"} }]}
  }
}
```

I’m getting following error (most of the error omitted for brevity):

```
Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\"query\":{\"filtered\":{\"filter\":{\"bool\":{\"must_not\":[{\"ids\":{\"values\":[\"one\",\"two\"]}}]}}},\"bool\":{\"must_not\":[{\"wildcard\":{\"url\":\"*.biz\"}}]}}}]]]; nested: SearchParseException[[sites_20150502][4]: query[ConstantScore(BooleanFilter(-_uid:site#one _uid:site#two))],from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [No parser for element [must_not]]]; }]","status":400}
```

My ES version is 1.1.1.

Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: Try `{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [
        { "wildcard": {"url": "*.biz"} },
        {"ids": {"values": ["one", "two"]}}
      ]
    }
  }
}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combining queries with filters should be done with [`filtered` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-filtered-query.html), which requires `query` and `filter` arguments:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must_not": [
            { wildcard: {url: "*.biz"} }
          ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must_not": [
            {ids: {values: ["one", "two"]}
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```